# Applications affected by memory performance

Tags: performance, memory-access

I'm writing a paper on the topic of applications affected more by memory performance than processor performance. I've got a lot written regarding the gap between the two, however I can't seem to find anything about the applications that might benefit more from memory performance.

I suppose these are applications that make a large amount of memory references, but I have no idea what kind of applications would make such large number of references to make it stand out?

Can you please give me any pointers on how to proceed, some links?

Comment: Databases? The algorithms used for them are compared with number of memory accesses instead of raw asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Maybe cache oblivious algorithms and data structures are a good place to look.

Comment: Sorting and searching.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is mostly restricted by the number of cache lines you have to read. Let's say you have 256 bit = 32 bytes cache lines: Then reading one byte from RAM takes almost as long as reading 32 bytes. So an application that reads small amounts of data from random locations takes much more time per byte.

Then the requirement is of course that your data doesn't fit into cache. So random reads of small items in a range that exceeds cache size is bad.

Next, you will often have to do address translation: You have a logical address, but your processor needs the physical address. For that you have a page table, with one entry in the page table often covering 4KB. So if each access goes into a different page, then each access needs to read a different page table entry, and if you use more page table entries than are cached, you go slower again.

So worst case are applications that access small amounts of data in a large area, at random locations far apart. And of course modifies them which takes longer again.

For example, take a two gigabyte byte array and write

```
for (j = 0; j < 65536; ++j)
    for (I = 0; I < 2000000000; I += 65536)
        array [I + j] += 1;
```

This may take two reads from RAM and one write for each access.